# Javascript countdown closure issue

Tags: javascript, closures, countdown

I have a for loop where I get the start number for my countdown. I want to use that number outside the for loop and here comes the closure problem.

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    var number = response[i].number; //the number is 10
    getNumber(number);
};
```

So I thought I should call a function that returns that number so I can use it somewhere else:

```
function getNumber(number) {
    return number;
}
```

But when I try to do this, I get an undefined instead of 10:

```
var globalVariableForNumber = getNumber();
```

What I know I am doing wrong is calling getNumber() without the parameter when assigning the value to my variable, but how else should I do it?

The number comes from an ajax call that has more numbers in it (response[i].number). I then want to use those numbers to be the start timers of my countdown. So if the number is 10, then my countdown will start from 10.
Thank you.

Comment: try doing this var `var globalVariableForNumber = getNumber` not calling the function but assigning it, so we dont just set the return value to the variable.

Comment: I don't get it. Should I not define the function and instead create the variable and assigning it getNumber? I'm sorry, but it makes no sense to me for some reason.

Comment: Calling a function does not store the value in it - are you looking to extract one value out of `response` or transform each entry in response into the value in the `number` key?

Comment: Just omit the `()` from this `var globalVariableForNumber = getNumber();`

Comment: I don't even understand what you try to do. Why do you use a for loop? Where is the countdown, how will it be called? And closures don't work like that. They are created when a function returns another function, referencing a variable from the enclosing one.

Comment: number is out of scope for the function, it has to be declared higher up in the scope chain

Comment: The number comes from an ajax call that has more numbers in it (response[i].number). I then want to use those numbers to be the start timers of my countdown. So if the number is 10, then my countdown will start from 10.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var response = [
  {number:5},
  {number:6},
  {number:7},
  {number:8},
  {number:9},
  {number:10}
]

var number;
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    number = response[i].number; //the number is 10
    console.log(getNumber());
};
function getNumber() {
    return number;
}

// try it again later...
console.log(getNumber());
```

Again, you should just be calling number directly. But for the purpose of this question you have to declare `number` in a higher scope.

[image]

Comment: I still get the number as undefined

Comment: what is the result of console.log(`response[i].number`)?

Comment: It is 10. When I console.log the number inside the getNumber(), I still get 10. But when I want to use the variable number anywhere else, it's undefined.

Comment: Yes but you are console logging inside the for loop. What if I want to have a variable called newVariable and assign the value to it? I mean outside the for loop and the function, just a global variable.

Comment: it returns whatever value is assigned to number. In this case 10. Which is why this is confusing I think... The value is defined in an outer scope so you can access it directly. If you wanted to access it from outside your scope you can do this... http://jsbin.com/jokamawevu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I've embellished a bit there, `getNumber` in the jsbin returns the value at a given index. Which is what Im kinda guessing you really wanted.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is creating a function that takes exactly one parameter and returns that parameter when it is called. Return is a fancy way of saying that if you say `foo=bar()` then `foo` is whatever `bar()` returned.

In your code, calling `getNumber()` with no parameter returns `undefined` because it just returns the parameter. What you should do instead is not return the parameter, but instead set the global variable to it like so:

```
function getNumber(number) {
    globalVariableForNumber = number;
}
```

Now, just get the number by running:

```
globalVariableForNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Scope

> The current context of execution. The context in which values and
>   expressions are "visible," or can be referenced. If a variable or
>   other expression is not "in the current scope," then it is unavailable
>   for use. Scopes can also be layered in a hierarchy, so that child
>   scopes have access to parent scopes, but not vice versa.
>
> A function serves as a closure in JavaScript, and thus creates a
>   scope, so that (for example) a variable defined exclusively within the
>   function cannot be accessed from outside the function or within other
>   functions.

Consider this example of scopes that your code could be declared and called:

```
function ImInGlobalScope(){ //Function declared in global scope

 //Lets call this block 1
 for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    var number = response[i].number; //Inside function scope
    getNumber(number)
 };

 //Lets call this block 2
 function getNumber(number){ //In same scope than for statement
    return number; //block 3
 }

}

var globalVariableForNumber = getNumber();
```

With this example getNumber is undefined because it belongs to ImInGlobalScope() scope. Consider another scenario of scopes for your code.

```
function ImInGlobalScope(){ //Function declared in global scope

 //Lets call this block 1
 for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    var number = response[i].number; //Inside function scope
    getNumber(number)
 };

}

 //Lets call this block 2
 function getNumber(number){ //In same scope than for statement
    return number; //block 3
 }

var globalVariableForNumber = getNumber();
```

I believe the above is what your scenario is: `getNumber` is on global scope but number is ImInGlobalScope().

So when you're calling `var globalVariableForNumber = getNumber();` We have the following:

```
 function getNumber(number){ //Number is not being passed so is undefined
    return number; //no variable named number exists in this scope so it will return undefined.
 }
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.